# Azure GetMachineGoalState dying from HTTP 410 error

Tags: azure

My Azure web role is constantly recycling.

The `WaAppAgent.log` file on my Azure web role contains a whole stream of these errors:

```
[00000008] [05/15/2012 00:10:20.90] GetMachineGoalState() failed with exception: Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.WebProtocolException: Server Error: Gone (Gone) ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (410) Gone.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.WebHttpChannelProxy`1.Invoke(IMessage msg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.RoleContainer.Protocol.IControlSystem.GetMachineGoalState()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.GuestAgent.ContainerStateMachine.ControlSystem.GetGoalState().
[00000008] [05/15/2012 00:10:20.90] Caught exception in pre-initialization heartbeat thread, will continue heartbeats: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.GuestAgent.ContainerStateMachine.ContainerStateManager.InitialHeartbeatThread(Object waitEvent)
[00000005] [05/15/2012 00:10:23.24] Agent runtime initialized.
```

The Azure service status dashboard says everything is green on their side, but it always says that unless the entire platform is down in a smoldering heap so I don't really trust it at all.

Is this my problem, or theirs?

Comment: The logging isn't helping a lot. Can you add some extra logging information to the constructor and the OnStart method on your RoleEntryPoint?

Answer (score 2):

I take your statement that you are using Full IIS based Windows Azure Web Role. I have seen such error with VM Role but with Web Role it seems very strange. I wouldn't weight much on your logs either at this time because it may mislead to wrong direction.

If your Web role status shows green (Ready) state but your site is not available then issue could be related to application itself because green or ready state means the role host process (in this case waiishost.exe) is healthy. It would be rare occurrence when role status is green and your role host process is unhealthy. Based on what you have provided either there is an issue within the VM startup sequence means your role not even started however the portal must not show ready state.

Please log into your Azure VM using RDP and..

1. Check first that WaIISHost.exe process is running or not.. keep an eye in this process for 2 minutes to check if this process is crashing and restarting again
2. Please check application event log because it should have some pattern of exception to find the root cause
3. Please check recent Azurebootstrapper and iisconfigurator logs located in C:\logs folder for any specific issue during VM boot and IIS start respectively.

At last please backup the logs (drive C:\logs and C:\Resources), please try rebooting your instance. Still have problem contact Windows Azure support team:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/